# Is there a method to change inter-item gap?

Tags: spacing, lists

I think a lot of people may be wondering this function, and I know there must be a great answer of this question. However, I cannot find it maybe because I do not know an adequate keyword for this problem.

I use the following code right after \begin{document} when I use beamer.

```
\let\OLDitemize\itemize
\let\OLDenumerate\enumerate
\renewcommand\itemize{\OLDitemize\addtolength{\itemsep}{??\baselineskip}}
\renewcommand\enumerate{\OLDenumerate\addtolength{\itemsep}{???\baselineskip}}
```

Then, I can adjust the inter-item-gap of itemize environment by substituting number into ??. Likewise, so can one of enumerate environment by doing number into ???.

For example, if I change 2 into ?? and 4 into ???, then the whole of inter-item-gap of itemize and enumerate environments are changed.

However, I want adjust gap of items according to item level in the whole of the program. That is, if I write the following code,

```
\begin{itemize}
    \item a
    \item b
    \item c
    \begin{itemize}
        \item d
        \item e
        \item f
    \end{itemize}
    \item g
    \item h
    \item i
\end{itemize}
```

the result I want to get is like the following:
[image: sep]

Please let me know how to change item-gap according to the level of items.
As occasion arises, I am using \vspace command like \vspace{.7\baselineskip}. This makes the code so dirty to become unreadable.

Actually, label is out of my point. I want to set the gap of item at will, regardless of whether itemize or enumerate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the `enumitem` package, you can specify the spacing parameters independently for each level of the `itemize`, with `\seteumerate[<level>]{}`.  Below, I show it with a unique `itemsep` and `topsep`, though all the spacing parameters may be brought into play.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setitemize[1]{itemsep=10pt,topsep=10pt}
\setitemize[2]{itemsep=0pt,topsep=-2pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
    \item a
    \item b
    \item c
    \begin{itemize}
        \item d
        \item e
        \item f
    \end{itemize}
    \item g
    \item h
    \item i
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

P.S.  The MWE works in `beamer`, too.  However, Alan Munn points out in a comment that because `beamer` modifies the list environments to make them overlay-aware, it really doesn't play nicely with `enumitem`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setitemize[1]{itemsep=10pt,topsep=10pt}
\setitemize[2]{itemsep=0pt,topsep=-2pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{beamer frame title}
\begin{itemize}
    \item a
    \item b
    \item c
    \begin{itemize}
        \item d
        \item e
        \item f
    \end{itemize}
    \item g
    \item h
    \item i
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh my god. It doesn't work on Beamer!

Comment: @Danny_Kim I updated my answer to show that, yes, it does work in `beamer`.

Comment: @Danny_Kim In my MWE, I `\setitemize` in the preamble.  However, if your settings are overriding those, you can always choose the `\setitemize` in the actual `frame`.

Comment: just adding \usepackage{enumitem} makes errors. "TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [grouping levels=255].\labelenumi ->{\labelenumi }\end{frame}." and "Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!."

Comment: @Danny_Kim It sounds to me that you have a typo/bug elsewhere in your code that remains innocuous unless `enumitem` is loaded.  What I would try in this case is to re-enable `enumitem`, but start commenting out parts of your code until you get it to compile.  Once you locate the section of code that provokes the failure, you can examine it more closely for syntactical errors.

Comment: I don't know why this happen. Just I found that enumerate environment causes error located in itemize environment.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Because `beamer` modifies the list environments to make them overlay-aware, it really doesn't play nicely with `enumitem`.

Comment: @Danny_Kim See Alan's comment above.  Perhaps the best approach is to try to isolate a minimum example that shows the specific `beamer`/`enumitem` problem.  It could always be asked as a new question.

Comment: Thank you very much Alan and Steven. For now, because I have to finish this material until today, I will change them one by one. Code maybe become dirty, though.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\newcommand\nosep{\vspace{-1ex}\setlength\itemsep{-0.75ex}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{foo}{bar}
\begin{itemize}
    \item a
    \item b
    \item c
    \begin{enumerate}\nosep
        \item d
        \item e
        \item f
    \end{enumerate}
    \item g
    \item h
    \item i
\end{itemize}   
\end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for answer. Should I set whenever I use the item?

Comment: Yes, in all cases where you want the reduced space.

Comment: Isn't there any methods to set the whole document at once? Imagine the line of codes is big. Then how can I change step by step, when I want to change the gap in the entire,

Comment: not really, because you have to know the situation: re you are inside another list environment or not. And, of course, beamer already redefines all list environments. With another document class, like article, it is pretty simple to get such behaviour.

Comment: Ah, thank you. my situation is that I have already a lot of pages made by beamer. However, I want to change the gap of all items. TT