# changing \itemsep only at top level of list environment

Tags: lists, conditionals, lengths

I'm not a LaTeX programmer, but I have to deal with this bit. I have a class file defining a `questionlist` environmet. This is a list environment which can be nested. I want the `\itemsep` to be set different from the default only for the top level, i.e. lowest depth. How can I do that?

The code is here (taken from the class file):

```
\newcount\@qlistdepth \@qlistdepth = 0
\@definecounter{qlisti}
\@definecounter{qlistii}
\@definecounter{qlistiii}
\@definecounter{qlistiv}
\def\questionlist{%
  \ifnum \@qlistdepth >\thr@@\@toodeep\else
    \advance\@qlistdepth\@ne
    \edef\@qlistctr{qlist\romannumeral\the\@qlistdepth}%
      \expandafter
      \list
        \csname label\@qlistctr\endcsname
        {\parsep1ex%
         \itemsep1ex%      this should only be used at depth=0
         \labelwidth1em%
         \labelsep0.5em%
         \leftmargin1.5em%
         \usecounter\@qlistctr\def\makelabel##1{\hss\llap{##1}}}
  \fi}
\let\endquestionlist = \endlist
\renewcommand\theqlisti{\@arabic\c@qlisti}
\renewcommand\theqlistii{\@alph\c@qlistii}
\renewcommand\theqlistiii{\@roman\c@qlistiii}
\renewcommand\theqlistiv{\@Alph\c@qlistiv}
\newcommand\labelqlisti{\theqlisti.}
\newcommand\labelqlistii{(\theqlistii)}
\newcommand\labelqlistiii{\theqlistiii.}
\newcommand\labelqlistiv{\theqlistiv.}
```

---

In response to some of the comments, I'd like to say that I want exactly the **same outcome** as what was asked in [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/321994/is-there-a-method-to-change-inter-item-gap) (to answer Keks Dose), but not in any way by modifying my `.tex` file. Instead I want to amend the code given (hence this is not a duplicate). Perhaps there is a way to code the same list that I want with the `enumitem` package, but that's beyond my scope.

Comment: Please add an MWE. I suggest to put the code you provided into an MWE that uses the article documentclass and show us, what you would like to achieve.

Comment: Perhaps you should look into the `enumitem` package -- it allows to use a per-level definition of various settings, `itemsep` should be amongst them.

Comment: Related/duplicate?  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/321994/is-there-a-method-to-change-inter-item-gap

Comment: What should `\itemsep` be for other levels within `questionlist`?

Comment: @Werner the default, as stated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of setting the code explicitly, set it conditionally using

```
\ifnum\@qlistdepth=1 \itemsep1ex\fi
```

The above condition checks for the value of the `questionlist` depth counter. Since it's advanced at the time of use, the lowest depth is actually 1.

Here is a complete example with a rather large `\itemsep` set conditionally like above, just to highlight the choice:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcount\@qlistdepth \@qlistdepth = 0
\@definecounter{qlisti}
\@definecounter{qlistii}
\@definecounter{qlistiii}
\@definecounter{qlistiv}
\def\questionlist{%
  \ifnum \@qlistdepth >\thr@@\@toodeep\else
    \advance\@qlistdepth\@ne
    \edef\@qlistctr{qlist\romannumeral\the\@qlistdepth}%
      \expandafter
      \list
        \csname label\@qlistctr\endcsname
        {\parsep1ex%
         \ifnum\@qlistdepth=1\itemsep5ex\fi%      this should only be used at depth = 0
         \labelwidth1em%
         \labelsep0.5em%
         \leftmargin1.5em%
         \usecounter\@qlistctr\def\makelabel##1{\hss\llap{##1}}}
  \fi}
\let\endquestionlist = \endlist
\renewcommand\theqlisti{\@arabic\c@qlisti}
\renewcommand\theqlistii{\@alph\c@qlistii}
\renewcommand\theqlistiii{\@roman\c@qlistiii}
\renewcommand\theqlistiv{\@Alph\c@qlistiv}
\newcommand\labelqlisti{\theqlisti.}
\newcommand\labelqlistii{(\theqlistii)}
\newcommand\labelqlistiii{\theqlistiii.}
\newcommand\labelqlistiv{\theqlistiv.}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{questionlist}
  \item First item - level 1
  \item Second item - level 1
  \begin{questionlist}
    \item First item - level 2
    \item Second item - level 2
    \begin{questionlist}
      \item First item - level 3
      \item Second item - level 3
      \begin{questionlist}
        \item First item - level 4
        \item Second item - level 4
        \item Last item - level 4
      \end{questionlist}
      \item Last item - level 3
    \end{questionlist}
    \item Last item - level 2
  \end{questionlist}
  \item Last item - level 1
\end{questionlist}

\end{document}
```

The default chosen otherwise will depend on the default font size chosen. That is, the lengths for `\itemsep` differ whether you use a `10pt`, `11pt` or `12pt` document class option.